# How to split the n test cases of one method among n methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have created a method where I test a trigger and I do something like this:

```
method(){
insert row1
assertequals...

insert row2
assertequals...

insert row3
assertequals...

...
}
```

So that I have n test cases in one method.
I would like to split the test cases in n methods.

I could do something like

```
method1(){
insert row1
assertequals...
}

method2(){
insert row1
insert row2
assertequals
}

method3(){
insert row1
insert row2
insert row3
assertequals
}
...
```

But it's pretty bad because I duplicate the insert statements.

Is it possible to do that in a smart way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write functions:

```
static void createRow1() {
  insert row1;
}
static void createRow2() {
  insert row2;
}
static void createRow3() {
  insert row3;
}
@isTest static void testMethod1() {
  createRow1();
  method1();
}
@isTest static void testMethod2() {
  createRow1();
  createRow2();
  method2();
}
@isTest static void testMethod3() {
  createRow1();
  createRow2();
  createRow3();
  method3();
}
```

Or, if it makes more sense, you can also chain method calls if the later rows always depend on the earlier rows:

```
static void createRow1() {
  insert row1;
}
static void createRow2() {
  createRow1();
  insert row2;
}
static void createRow3() {
  createRow2();
  insert row3;
}
@isTest static void testMethod1() {
  createRow1();
  method1();
}
@isTest static void testMethod2() {
  createRow2(); // also creates row1
  method2();
}
@isTest static void testMethod3() {
  createRow3(); // also creates row1 and row2
  method3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As sfdcfox describes, factoring code out into methods so that code can be re-used is a common approach. But often you need the result from one method in another method (particularly in assertions) so that signals using a class instead where you can have both code and data. That then allows individual test methods to be self-describing (if the method names are chosen well) and work at one level of abstraction (note no variables needed and no clutter):

```
@IsTest
static void method2() {
    new Fixture()
        .insertRow1()
        .insertRow2()
        .insertRow3()
        .assert();
}
```

Each method returning `this` allows the `.` chaining (see e.g. [FluentInterface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)), and putting each method on a separate line makes the code both more readable and ensures any stack trace points to the specific line.

The overall class would be something like this:

```
@IsTest
private class MyTest {

    private class Fixture {

        // These can be referenced inside this class and from the test methods
        Type1__c row1;
        Type2__c row2;
        Type3__c row3;

        Fixture insertRow1() {
            ...
            row1 = ...;
            return this;
        }

        Fixture insertRow2() {
            ...
            row2 = ...;
            return this;
        }

        Fixture insertRow3() {
            ...
            row3 = ...;
            return this;
        }

        Fixture assert() {
            ....
            return this;
        }
    }

    @TestSetup
    static void setup() {
        // Insert data used by most methods (if any)
    }

    @IsTest
    static void method1() {
        new Fixture()
            .insertRow1()
            .assert();
    }

    @IsTest
    static void method2() {
        new Fixture()
            .insertRow1()
            .insertRow2()
            .assert();
    }

    @IsTest
    static void method3() {
        new Fixture()
            .insertRow1()
            .insertRow2()
            .insertRow3()
            .assert();
    }
}
```

This may be overkill in this case, but worth becoming familiar with as a way to keep complex tests cleaner.